# Comparing two arrays with nested for loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Problem: Given two arrays `x` and `y`, `x` being **Alice's** score, and `y` being **Bob's** score. Compare similar indices between Alice and Bob and give 1 point to whomever is greater than for every compared indices (no point if Equal).

INPUT:

```
x = [4,1,6]
y = [1,1,5]
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
{Alice:2, Bob: 0}
```

MY CODE:

```
x = [4,1,6]
y = [1,1,5]

results = {'Alice':0, 'Bob': 0}

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
  for (var j = 0; j < y.length; j++){
    if (x[i] > y[j]){
      results['Alice'] += 1
    }else if (x[i] < y[j]){
      results['Bob'] += 1
    }
  }
}

console.log(results)
```

ACTUAL OUTPUT:

```
{Alice: 5, Bob: 2}
```

QUESTION:

Where did I go wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you shouldn't use a nested loop. What you are doing here is comparing all of Alice's results against all of Bob's, in this order:

- Alice[0] vs. Bob[0] - 1 point to Alice
- Alice[0] vs. Bob[1] - 1 point to Alice
- Alice[0] vs. Bob[2] - 1 point to Bob
- Alice[1] vs. Bob[0] - Tie
- Alice[1] vs. Bob[1] - Tie
- Alice[1] vs. Bob[2] - 1 point to Bob
- Alice[2] vs. Bob[0] - 1 point to Alice
- Alice[2] vs. Bob[1] - 1 point to Alice
- Alice[2] vs. Bob[2] - 1 point to Alice

To fix this, get rid of the inner loop and `j`, and just use `i`.

```js
var x = [4, 1, 6]
var y = [1, 1, 5]

var results = {
  'Alice': 0,
  'Bob': 0
}

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  if (x[i] > y[i]) {
    results['Alice'] += 1
  } else if (x[i] < y[i]) {
    results['Bob'] += 1
  }
}

console.log(results)
```

Answer (score 3):

The error is that you look at all possible pairs with the first value from the first array, and the second from the second. But only need to compare values that are in the *same position*. So you need only one loop:

```js
x = [4,1,6]
y = [1,1,5]

results = {'Alice':0, 'Bob': 0}

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    if (x[i] > y[i]){
      results['Alice'] += 1
    }else if (x[i] < y[i]){
      results['Bob'] += 1
    }
}

console.log(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing each elements of x array with all elements of y array. For getting your output expected you need to compare the first element or array x with the first element of array y, the second with the second....

I hope this helps!!